# OData - Breeze - Custom Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, odata, breeze

I am using Breeze for a SPA application. The backend data is coming from accessing an API (not EF).

I exposed "Tasks" as a Queryable collection.

In some cases, I want to request a single Task by Id. The OData filter will be sent to the server, but then Breeze, will have to query all Tasks in the database and then apply filter.

Is there a way to intercept the OData filters, and go get myself the single record requested?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Breeze *EntityQuery.withParameters* method.

```
// Client
var query = new EntityQuery("GetTaskById").withParameters( { "taskId": 126 });
myEntityManager.executeQuery(query).then(...)

// Server
[HttpGet]
public Task GetTaskById(int taskId) {
   // your task code.
}
```

Note that you can return either a scalar result or an IQueryable which means that you can also mix and match *EntityQuery.where* clauses with *EntityQuery.withParameter* clauses.

Hope this helps.